# getting selected value of selectBox using jQuery/ajax in symfony 3 project

Tags: ajax, twig

I posted a question earlier asking about the possibility to get the selected value of a selectBox and assign it to a service being called in twig.
I managed after some research to implement what some guys here suggested.

Using ajax I sent the selected value to my php controller which sent back my selected value to my interface and yéy twig can see the variable!

here is the ajax call:

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('listFolders1').on('change', function() {
             var selected = $('#listFolders1 :selected').text();
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "{{ path('ess') }}",
                 data: selected,
                 success: function (response) {
                     console.log(response);
                 },
                 error: function (response, xhr, status) {
                     alert("error" + status);
                 }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is my controller

```
public function essAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->request->get('data');
    return $this->render('PrestaShopTestBundle:Test:full.html.twig', array(
        'data' => $data,
    ));
   //return new Response($data);
}
```

and of course this is my routing file

```
ess:
path:    /ess
defaults: { _controller: PrestaShopTestBundle:Test:ess }
```

I'm trying to display my variable like this in twig

```
{% if data is defined %}
              {{ data }}
          {% endif %}
```

there are no errors, it just IGNORES me. Nothing happens even the url doesn't change.

PS: ListFolders is my SelectBox

Comment: Your `data` variable isn't correct. You have to pass a valid object in order to make it appear in your `$_POST` variable e.g.  `data : { 'selected': selected },`, this will make `$_POST` contain the index `selected` with the selected value

Comment: yeah that helped :) i can display my data in the console now .. but still can't access it via twig :(

Comment: In the success callback you place code to update your frontend e.g; `success: function(response) { $('#ess').html(response); },`. You've already accessed and processed your ajax request with `twig` inside the action `essAction`. That part is already done, that ajax request now received the output of the `essAction` back in javascript. Which u now need to display.

Comment: yeah that i can do .. i can display it in a div my problem is that i want to assign it to  a twig variable like this {% set data=data %} and that is not happening :(

Comment: It's just not possible to do this. You have to understand that `twig` is a server side technology, `twig` gets compiled into `PHP`, which get interpreted at the server and then sent towards the client. This mean all the `twig`/`php` is already processed before the user can modify anything to it. The only thing now u can do without a page reload (and using session or storage of any kind) is using `ajax` and update the frontend accordingly.

Comment: okay .. thank you at least i learned something new .. i'll have to think of another algorithm to perform my task .. thanks a lot :D